# I want an animation to trigger on active and continue once the active state is gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I want an animation to start when someone clicks a button but to continue/finish when they unclick.

```
&:active > .ripple {
    -webkit-animation: ripple 3s infinite;
  }
```

The animation only continues so long as the button is held down. Is there a way to achieve this with just css or will I need to use JS? I'm pretty green when it comes to JS so was hoping to achieve with just css.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean :active or :hover?

Comment: Crap. Meant :Active, I put the wrong code in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the CSS property

&:focus > .ripple {

-webkit-animation: ripple 3s infinite; 
}

It's basically the 'onclick' in JavaScript

Tell me if if works for you

Cheers !